# WCF Service hosted in Windows Service hangs on stop

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF Service hosted in a Windows service [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service).
I have scheduled nightly restart of the service, but sometimes the restart fails and the service remains/hangs in Stopping state and the EXE process has to be killed manually. It looks likely that it hangs on line `_ESSServiceHost.Close();`, because nothing after that line is logged it the log file. It is possible but not very likely that the service gets the stop request when it is busy. 
Moreover the underlying process cannot be killed because it is dependent on services.exe, so only server restart works.

What could be wrong with this approach?

```
  protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_ESSServiceHost != null)
            {
                _ESSServiceHost.Close();
                _ESSServiceHost = null;
                //Never reaches the following line
                Tools.LogInfo("Services stopped.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Tools.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
```

This is how I stop the service:

```
    private bool StopService(ServiceController scESiftServer)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (scESiftServer.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            try
            {
                scESiftServer.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Tools.LogEvent("Exception ...");
                return false;
            }
            while (scESiftServer.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped && i < 120)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                scESiftServer.Refresh();
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (scESiftServer.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
        {
            //This line gets executed
            Tools.LogEvent("Failed within 120 sec...");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Tools.LogEvent("OK ...");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

---

Could something like this help?

```
var task = Task.Run(() => _ESSServiceHost.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(299)));
if (!task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300)))
{
    _ESSServiceHost.Abort();
}
```

But _ESSServiceHost.Abort() should be called internally by the Close method if needed.
Target framework is 4.5, installed is .NET 4.7.2.

Found out that probably the service hangs after series of malformed requests. `Expected record type 'Version', found '71'.` etc.

Comment: Try to use [Close(TimeSpan timeout)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms405497(v=vs.110).aspx) (with less than 120s timeout) method instead of `Close()`. If this helps then you have long running task in WCF service (which `Close()` waits to end). And that means you need to increase your 120s WindowsService stopping timeout or deal with long running WCF task.

Comment: @Reniuz I thought that `scESiftServer.Stop();` runs asynchronously just sending a message to Windows service system. Do you think that making the interval longer or waiting for service to stop within my `StopService` method  can fix the problem with service remaining in "Stopping"  state?

Comment: Increase interval or close WCF with timeout or even call Abort() just for testing purpose. I would suggest to look at the WCF service, why it is not closing, what long running tasks do you have there?

Comment: I do not see any unfinished long running tasks in the log, but they have had some network problems on the server. The service in the stopping state is still able to execute tasks that are not connected with WCF service (timer tasks). I can see quite a lot of exceptions in `es_tracelog.svclog`.

Comment: @Reniuz I have added the suggested timeout but the Close method hangs anyway even with the timeout specified. There were no requests to the service at the time it hanged, it was simply the restart of the service.

Comment: Have you tried to use Abort instead of Close?

Comment: @Reniuz I would use  Abort only when Close fails, but Close just hangs, not sure how to do it.

Comment: I am not suggesting to use Abort permanently, add it just for testing purpose to see if it breaks connection.

Comment: Thank you, I decided to add another question here, perhaps I shall merge them together and delete the other, not sure now, because still do not know the exact cause. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51703455/wcf-service-how-to-read-the-log-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found in the `svclog` file that my service hangs after series of malformed request that happen on Saturday and Sunday at approx. 5:15 AM. The error messages were `Expected record type 'Version', found '71'.`, `Error while reading message framing format at position 0 of stream (state: ReadingVersionRecord)`. But I could not find the cause of theese malformed request series, so I tried to fix the service to withstand the "attack".

I have modified the `OnStop` method as follows:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    try
    {
        if (_ESSServiceHost != null)
        {
            Tools.LogInfo("Stopping ESService.");
            var abortTask = Task.Run(() => _ESSServiceHost.Abort());
            var closeTask = Task.Run(() => _ESSServiceHost.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300)));
            try
            {
                if (_ESSServiceHost.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    Tools.LogInfo("ESSServiceHost.State == CommunicationState.Faulted");
                    if (!abortTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)))
                        Tools.LogInfo("Failed to Abort.");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!closeTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(301)))
                    {
                        Tools.LogInfo("Failed to Close - trying Abort.");
                        if (!abortTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)))
                            Tools.LogInfo("Failed to Abort.");

                    }                            
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Tools.LogException(ex, "ESSServiceHost.Close");
                try
                {
                    Tools.LogInfo("Abort.");
                    if (!abortTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)))
                        Tools.LogInfo("Failed to Abort.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    Tools.LogException(ex2, "ESSServiceHost.Abort");

                }
            }
            _ESSServiceHost = null;
            Tools.LogInfo("ESService stopped.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Tools.LogException(ex,"OnStop");
    }
}
```

Today on Monday I have checked the svclog and the "attacks" with malformed request remained there but my service lived happily through it. So it seemed to be fixed. Moreover only:

> Stopping ESService.
>
> ESService stopped.

events were logged in my log file. No aborts etc. So I guess that putting the `Close` call on a separate thread fixed the problem but absolutely do not know why.